# angular routing, prevent redirect if I'm already in sub route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

suppose I have a route 'settings' with some subroutes like 'profile' and 'billing'

```
---- setting (redirect to profile if empty)
        |
        ---- profile
        |
        ---- billing
```

- my question is if i am in `/settings/billing` and i press redirect to `/settings` is it possible to skip the redirect since i am already in the settings sub route.

in my case I'm using `routerLink` directive for redirection
if there is a solution using `router.redirect('path')` It is ok.

```
{
    path: '',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'billing',
        component: BillingComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'profile',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Can you please tell, when you say 'press redirect' , is it a button or an hyper link on the page? There are different ways to achieve what are you looking for. Once you will provide this information, I will be able to assist.

Comment: sorry my misunderstanding but... do you ask about `{path: '',component: ProfileComponent}`?,

Comment: for my case I'm using routerLink directive